# I Can't delete a member variable of wxApp class

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a `CTaskBarIcon *m_pTaskbar` member variable in myApp class.
That variable will take an instance of `CTaskBarIcon` object.
When deleting the `m_pTaskbar` from within `onExit` method a runtime error occurs when quitting the program, and cause of the problem is to delete `m_pTaskbar` variable.

**app.h**

```
#include "taskBarIcon.h"
class myApp: public wxApp{
public:
    // ....
private:
    CTaskBarIcon *m_pTaskbar; // = NULL
};
```

**app.cpp**

```
int myApp::OnExit() {
    if (m_pTaskbar != NULL) {
        delete m_pTaskbar; // <-- The problem here
        m_pTaskbar = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
int myApp::OnRun() {
    mainFrm *_mainFrm = mainFrm::getInstance(); // The main window
    _mainFrm->Show(false);
    m_pTaskbar = new CTaskBarIcon(_mainFrm);
    m_pTaskbar->SetIcon(wxIcon("appIcon"), _mainFrm->GetTitle());      
    return wxApp::OnRun();
}
```

**CTaskBarIcon.cpp**

```
CTaskBarIcon::CTaskBarIcon(mainFrm *handler) : m_pHandler(handler), m_pMenu(NULL) {
    this->Bind(wxEVT_TASKBAR_CLICK, &CTaskBarIcon::rightButton_Click, this);
}

CTaskBarIcon::~CTaskBarIcon() {
    if (m_pMenu != NULL) {
        delete m_pMenu;
        m_pMenu = NULL;
    }
}


void CTaskBarIcon::rightButton_Click(wxTaskBarIconEvent & event) {
    PopupMenu(CreatePopupMenu());
}

void CTaskBarIcon::popupMenu_showWindow(wxCommandEvent & event) {
    m_pHandler->Iconize(false); // 'm_pHandler' is the main window
    m_pHandler->Show();
    m_pHandler->Raise();
    this->Destroy();
}

void CTaskBarIcon::popupMenu_showAbout(wxCommandEvent & event) {
    aboutFrm aboutWindow(m_pHandler, "About");
    aboutWindow.ShowModal();
    aboutWindow.Raise();
}

void CTaskBarIcon::popupMenu_exit(wxCommandEvent & event) {
    m_pHandler->Close(true);
    this->Destroy();
}

wxMenu* CTaskBarIcon::CreatePopupMenu() {
    this->m_pMenu = new wxMenu();
    m_pMenu->Append(wxID_SHOW, "&Show");
    m_pMenu->Append(wxID_ABOUT, "&About");
    m_pMenu->Append(wxID_EXIT, "E&xit");
    m_pMenu->Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &CTaskBarIcon::popupMenu_showWindow, this, wxID_SHOW);
    m_pMenu->Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &CTaskBarIcon::popupMenu_showAbout, this, wxID_ABOUT);
    m_pMenu->Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &CTaskBarIcon::popupMenu_exit, this, wxID_EXIT);
    return this->m_pMenu;
}
```

**Is there a problem with my code?**

Comment: Are you sure the usages of `this->Destroy();` are correct? When you debug the code, is `m_pTaskBar` pointing to an already-deleted instance by the time `myApp::OnExit()` runs?

Comment: `delete` is not recommended for `wxWindow` and `destroy` needs to be used: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/overview_windowdeletion.html

Comment: @LionKing, which OS you are running on? Is the sample works fine?

Comment: @Igor: WIndows. Works fine except when quitting the program.

Comment: @LionKing, you mean even the sample fails? Did you modify the sample in any way? In this case you should file a bug on the trac.wxwidgets.org...

Comment: @Igor: do you mean that my code doesn't have any problem? or what, sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: @LionKing, did you try the `taskbar` sample? Did it work for you? If it does - what do you do differently?

Comment: @LionKing, also out of curiosity - why did you call `this->Destroy()`? You don't want the task bar icon anymore?

Comment: @Igor: I want to know when to use `Destroy()` and `delete`, could you explain to me if it is possible, please?

Comment: @LionKing, it is not the question I ask. I wonder why do you need to delete the task bar icon? You don't need it anymore? Or you just experimenting?

Comment: @Igor: I want the taskbar icon to be hidden when the main window is not iconized (visible), and be visible when the main window is iconized (invisible).

Comment: @LionKing, in this case you shouldn't call `Destroy()`. It does exactly what it says - it destroys the control, but doesn't set the pointer to `NULL`.  So later when you (or wxWidgets) is deleting the pointer it is crashing, since you have a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with deleting a `wxTaskBarIcon` from its own event handler. Can you try if using `CallAfter([this] { Destroy(); })` instead of just calling `Destroy()` directly fixes the problem?

Comment: Is that the only solution to that problem or there are some mistakes in my code?